# how to deserialize complex json to hashtable+array style

Tags: c#, json.net

here is my code:

```
        string json = "{'047084de7e289476991970194dd14513':{'reload':[]}}";
        var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        Console.WriteLine($"{r}");
```

in my json, hashtable include inner hashtable, the `r["047084de7e289476991970194dd14513"]` result is jobject, but I hope its a hashtable, how should I do?

I hope find a way like javascript `JSON.parse` to get a object that all inner key and value can accessable

I use mono in linux, so I cannot use JavaScriptSerializer

Answer (score 0):

I find JsonConvert.DeserializeObject return JObject or JArray are like Hashtable and Array, so if parse result is jobject, I can cast result to JObject

```
        string json = "{'047084de7e289476991970194dd14513':{'reload':[]}}";
        var r = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        Console.WriteLine($"{r["047084de7e289476991970194dd14513"]}");
```